# Java equivalent of C#'s Console.ReadLine();

Tags: c#, java, readline

I've been asking questions about C# and Java because I'm a new programmer, and I was told that the best way to learn is to learn all of the languages at relativley the same time. I've worked with C#, and now I'm on Java, so I'm wondering: What is the Java equivalent of C#'s Console.ReadLine? In C#, I can do this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");
 int age = Console.ReadLine();
```

So, how can I do this same basic thing in Java? I'm trying to put many basic lessons together, and I can't find the correct way to do this piece anywhere.

Comment: Learn all the languages?! Maybe learn a few at once

Comment: Learning all the languages at once seems like a super ambitious idea. Maybe gain some deeper experience with one and then branch out when you have a basic understanding.

Comment: *I was told that the best way to learn is to learn all of the languages at relativley the same time* Who told you this?

Answer (score 3):

Use scanner

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = s.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int age = input.nextInt();
```